# Send Multiple email at same time with different body using webmail

Tags: c#, email, c#-4.0, smtp, webmail

I am using WebMail in mvc5 and i have a condition now to send emails to multiple user and each user's email body will be different from other . If i send them using loop then it will take to much time to return back to View . So , whats the best solution in this case ?

Here is my code to send a single email

```
 WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.UserName = "myemail";
        WebMail.From = "senderemail";
        WebMail.Password = "mypassword";
        WebMail.Send(to,
            "subject",
            "body");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be the fastest so you're only setting the non-specific stuff once.
You're effectively sending different emails, if body was the same i'd use bcc or cc.

```
void Send(IDictionary<string, string> emailDetails, string subject)
{

  WebMail.SmtpServer = ConfigHelper.SmtpServer;
  WebMail.SmtpPort = ConfigHelper.SmtpPort;
  WebMail.UserName = ConfigHelper.EmailUserName;
  WebMail.From = ConfigHelper.EmailFrom;
  WebMail.Password = ConfigHelper.Password;

  emailDetails.ToList().ForEach( e =>
  { 
    WebMail.Send(e.Key,
        subject,
        e.Value);
  });

}
```